# Regular expression to match phrases with special character

Tags: python, regex

Was wondering what is the best way to match "clear 18+ from your history" from "clear 18+ from your history? blah blah blah" is? Using Python.

I've tried this,

```
keyword = "clear 18+ from your history"
prepped_string = "clear 18+ from your history? blah blah blah"

is_flagged = False
if re.search(r'\b' + keyword + r'\b', prepped_string):
     is_flagged = True
```

The above code only works with no special character. If there is a special character like the plus sign, it won't work. Thanks in advance.

Here's the full code:

```
def _get_user_blacklist_weights(self, prepped_string, user):
        """
        Returns a list of (word, weight, reason) for every user word that is found.
        """
        out = []
        if user.blacklist:          
            matches = user.blacklist.search(prepped_string)
            for match in matches:
                is_flagged = False
                try:
                    if re.search(r'\b' + keyword + r'\b', prepped_string):
                        is_flagged = True
                except Exception as e:
                    # The condition below fixes both python 3.4 and 3.6 error message on repeating characters.
                    if (str(e)).startswith(C.REPEAT_ERROR_MESSAGES):
                        is_flagged = True
                    else: # pragma: no cover
                        error_logging(e)

                if is_flagged:
                    out.append((match, C.USER_BLACKLIST_MATCH_WEIGHT,
                            '%s or one of his/her accountability partners asked that "%s" be flagged.' % (user.person.first_name.title(), match)))               
        return out
```

Comment: I'm 90% certain that Wiktor would have closed this question, so I am also voting to close it.  An answer which just says to escape the `+` is effectively just fixing a typo IMHO.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it just a sample from the real code. All of the special characters doesn't work from the regex I did so I'm posting here to ask for help. I've also done lot's of research from here but I can't find that much my problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, it's not a typo, it needs a new function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re.escape`

**Ex:**

```
import re    
keyword = "clear 18+ from your history"
prepped_string = "clear 18+ from your history? blah blah blah"

is_flagged = False
if re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(keyword) + r'\b', prepped_string):
    is_flagged = True
print(is_flagged)  # -->True
```

Answer (score 4):

The `+` is interpreted as *one or more*. You can *escape* the `+`, or wrap it in a *character set*. For example:

```
keyword = r'clear 18\+ from your history'
```

or:

```
keyword = 'clear 18[+] from your history'
```

You can make use of [**`re.escape(..)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) if you want to automatically escape a string. For example:

```
>>> print(re.escape('clear 18+ from your history'))
clear\ 18\+\ from\ your\ history
```